# Edge list of a graph as a simple list of lists of pairs of integers?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a list of graph edges in the form:

```
e={UndirectedEdge[1,2], UndirectedEdge[3,4]}
```

How can I convert this to a simple list of lists: `e={{1,2},{3,4}}`?

Comment: `List @@@ e`, but don't assume that the list contains integers.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
e={UndirectedEdge[1,2], UndirectedEdge[3,4]};
e/.UndirectedEdge[x_,y_]->{x,y}
```

which instantly gives you

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

Comment: slightly better (?): `UndirectedEdge -> List`.

Answer (score 0):

> Edge list of a graph as a simple list of lists of pairs of integers?

First, note that the vertices of a graph are *not labelled with **consecutive** integers*! It is a common beginner mistake to assume this. In Mathematica, vertices can be anything, e.g. `Graph[{"a" <-> "b"}]`

Even when the vertices *are* integers, they may not be consecutive, and they may not be ordered. Example: `VertexDelete[CycleGraph[4], 2]`. Now the vertices are `{1, 3, 4}`.

---

If you want the edge list not in terms of vertices, but in terms of vertex indices (i.e. the position of each vertex in `VertexList[graph]`), then you can use

```
List @@@ EdgeList@IndexGraph[graph]
```

You can get the same *much* faster using

```
IGIndexEdgeList[graph]
```

using the [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

---

If all you need is a list of lists, keeping vertex names as they are, just use

```
List @@@ EdgeList[graph]
```